# DirectoryEntry path with server.company.local

Tags: c#, active-directory

Got a function where the user authenticate against active directory.
Works great when I only have it like this:

```
new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=" +"company" + ",DC=" + "local", userName, password)
```

In other active directory functions Im using `ContextType.Domain` like this:

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, GetContextName()))
```

But when im looking at ctx it get a "connectServer" to xxxxx.company.local where "xxxxx" is the server where we have the active directory on.
So how would I make the path to my `DirectoryEntry` with the xxxxx -server? 
Tried like this:

```
new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=" + "xxxxx" + "DC," +"company" + ",DC=" + "local", userName, password)
```

and this:

```
new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=" + "xxxxx" + "DC," +"company" + ",DC=" + "local", userName, password)
```

but neither did work. Im curious if it's any benefits to have the extra "xxxxx" -server in the path and how it would looked like, or should I only go with the "company" and "local" path that actually works nice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to connect to a specific server (i.e. domain controller) you can use the following syntax:

```
new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxxxx/DC=company,DC=local", userName, password)
```

I recommend not connecting to a specific domain controller unless you really need to. By leaving out the server name you allow your code to connect to what ever domain controller is online on your domain.  Specifying a specific server may be useful if you need to connect to a different domain.